# NSUserDefaults returns current time rather than stored time if app is killed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm saving the current `NSDate` in `NSUserDefaults` in order to compare it to the current time when the app returns to foreground or is activated again.

So I'm using this to store it:

```
NSUserDefaults *stateOfPlay = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDate *timeBackgrounded = [NSDate date];

[stateOfPlay setObject:timeBackgrounded forKey:@"timeBackgrounded"];
[stateOfPlay synchronize];
```

and this to retrieve it.

```
NSUserDefaults *stateOfPlay = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[stateOfPlay synchronize];

NSDate *timeBackgrounded = [stateOfPlay objectForKey:@"timeBackgrounded"];
```

Which all works fine when the app is backgrounded and returns. See this NSLog:

```
<Warning>: saved timeBackgrounded: 2013-04-13 12:21:01 +0000
...
<Warning>: read timeBackgrounded: 2013-04-13 12:21:01 +0000
<Warning>: current time: 2013-04-13 12:22:54 +0000
```

So far so good. But when I kill the app after backgrounding and then restart it, the time it was backgrounded is no longer returned from `NSUserDefaults`. Instead, it returns the current time.

```
<Warning>: saved timeBackgrounded: 2013-04-13 12:23:09 +0000
...
<Warning>: read timeBackgrounded: 2013-04-13 12:23:43 +0000
<Warning>: current time: 2013-04-13 12:23:43 +0000
```

The other things I'm storing (some integers) are returning fine when the app is started again. So what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

`NSUserDefaults` is being called via `NSNotificationCenter` like so:

Calling via `NSNotificationCenter`, like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver:self
selector:@selector(goBackground)
name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
object:nil];

//if app foregrounds or opens, adjust score for time in background

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver: self
selector: @selector(goForeground)
name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
object:nil];
```

I can see from the console that each of them is firing correctly when the app foregrounds or backgrounds; but after a kill the time returned from `NSUserDefaults` is the current time rather than the one that was stored there.

**EDIT #2**

I've found the problem - I'm initialising it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but not as pant of `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsDictionary]`. So it's getting overwritten every time the app fires up.

Adding the first setting into `defaultsDictionary` solves the problem by making sure it only gets initialised the very first time the application is launched.

Comment: In which methods are the two first snippets of code?

Answer (score 0):

hey while retrieving the data from NSUserDefaults dont do synchronize again according the apple doc

**synchronize**
Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.

so the date existing in that might modifying again.....

i hope this works well.........

Comment: I've tried it both with and without synchronize, and the result is the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see here is the place you are calling the getter/setter for NSUserDefaults. 
Check if it is updating all the time of opening app, view controller transitions etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem - I'm initialising it in -(void)didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but not as part of

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsDictionary]
```

So it's getting overwritten every time the app fires up.

Adding the first setting into defaultsDictionary solves the problem by making sure it only gets initialised the very first time the application is launched.